# Cakephp Localized Validation is not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Ok... I am feeling really stupid here, but can somebody help me pointing out what I am doing wrong?

My Model contains the following validation rules:

```
public $validate = array(
    'nome_completo' => array(
        'lettersandspaces' => array(
            'rule' => 'latinChars',
            'message' => 'Por favor, entre seu nome completo.',
        ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Por favor, entre seu nome completo.',
        )
    ),
    'cpfcnpj' => array(
            'rule' => array('ssn',null,'br'),
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'CPF Inválido!' 
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'message' => 'Por favor, entre um e-mail válido.',
        ),
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'O e-mail é um campo obrigatório.',
        )
    )       
);
```

I am calling App::uses('BrValidation', 'Localized.Validation'); at its beginning, but the BR version of SSN check doesn't seem to be called...

I have even placed some debug messages to check whether the code is being executed, but no debug gets logged... It's as if it is completely ignored by Cake...

I am using Cake 2.4.1... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read my comments under the selected answer...

I ended up doing SSN ("CPF" in Brazil) validation using jQuery, which works and is client-side, so it saves an HTTP request.

Good point about App::uses... Will look into it to ensure paths are OK, but since the package is in the standard location, I am not holding my hopes high there.

Comment: Sure you can use Jquery, but that doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `App::uses` doesn't throw an error if the file/class is not found.

Try adding a debug after the `App::uses` line:

```
debug(BrValidation::ssn('test'));
```

If you get a `Class 'BrValidation' not found` error, then you know it's not finding the file.

Comment: Localized.Validation is sort of a "standard" Cake package that the community maintains to extend those "basic" validation rules (such as 'ssn').  Good point remembering that `App::uses` doesn't complain when it doesn't find the files, but that doesn't seem to be the case as the package is in the standard location.